# phpcassa gives error on cql execution

Tags: php, cassandra, phpcassa

I have recently created a column family with `CREATE TABLE` in `cqlsh` console.

I have the following column family;

```
CREATE TABLE user (
  id timeuuid PRIMARY KEY,
  balance decimal,
  is_free boolean,
  player_id bigint,
)
```

I want to insert the following type of data;

```
{
    "player_id": 104,
    "balance": "0.00",
    "is_free": false,
    "bonus": "3+3+3"
}
```

when I do insert from `cqlsh` console the insertion is the following;

```
INSERT INTO keyspace.user (player_id, balance,is_free,bonus, id) 
VALUES (104,0.00,'3+3+3',67c5cb00-d814-11e2-9e13-59eb8e4538e5)
```

Id is generated by `UUID::uuid1()->string`

When I try to insert from `cqlsh`, it gives no error. However, in phpcassa, it gives the following error :

```
Expected key 'ID' to be present in WHERE clause for 'users'
```

I already set the client's cql version to 3.0.0 by

```
$pool->get()->client->set_cql_version("3.0.0");
```

I already tried to insert timeuuid field like that `'67c5cb00-d814-11e2-9e13-59eb8e4538e5'`

By the way, the `var_dump` of the variable `$cql` that is executed is the following;

```
string 'INSERT INTO keyspace.user (player_id,balance,is_free,bonus,id) VALUES (104,0.00,false,'3+3+3','ca256040-d819-11e2-ae08-f78171d975c3')'
```

What is the problem here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`execute_cql_query()` function does not seem to be working in cql_version 3.0.0

although cql 3 support is not official in phpcassa, `execute_cql3_query()` function works stable & well for me by using the following code;

```
$this->_connection_pool->get()->client->execute_cql3_query($cql, ConsistencyLevel::ONE);
```

where `$cql` is the following;

```
string 'INSERT INTO keyspace.user (player_id,balance,is_free,bonus,id)
        VALUES (104,0.00,false,'3+3+3',12128260-d8ea-11e2-b5b3-0be38f9377b6)'
```